# Can we use Virtual DOM along with GSAP?

Tags: reactjs, gsap, virtual-dom

Currently trying to build some React components using D3 math. However, when it comes to transition/animation, kind of facing a wall. It's not straightforward.

I saw folks are using libraries like GreenSock. How this affecting on Virtual DOM? Does GSAP also manipulates DOM directly? If yes, is not that NOGO for React?